# Error lower_case_table_names

Tags: mysql, c#, .net

No logro conectarme con mySQL mediante c# en VS2019
el error que obtengo es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

investigando en otros medios, me anime a cambiar la variable en my.conf y agregue la siguiente linea:

> lower_case_table_names=1

lo coloque en 0 para desactivarlo, pero el codigo sigue enviando el mismo error.
¿Como solucionarlo?

aquí mi código...

```
string CadenaConexion = "Server=127.0.0.1;User=root;Password=0122924301;Port=3306;database=dbcomputienda;SSL Mode=None";
    
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        conexion();
    }

    public void conexion()
    {
        MySqlConnection mySqlConnection = new MySqlConnection(CadenaConexion);

        try
        {
            mySqlConnection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error de conexion " + ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Conectado")
```

;        }